# Count values in the columns separated by ":"

Tags: r

I am new to r, and I have to count the values in a column that are separated by ":".

There are 4 categories in the dataset, and I have to count the number of actions per category. Each log_id represent a unique action in a category. If there are 2 or more categories for one log_id, it means that, that particular action will be counted towards all the categories mentioned.

The data look like this

```
user_id   log_id  categories
  001     1334    Perform:Sport_Well:Com.Tent
  001     1323    Com.Tent
  001     1212    Active
  002     1113    NA
  002     1478    Com.Tent:Active
  002     1134    Sport_Well:Perform
  002     1256    Perform
  002     1590    Perform
  002     1345    NA
  002     1478    Com.Tent
  002     1134    Sport_Well:Perform
  002     1256    Perform
  003     1590    Perform
  003     1345    Active:Perform
  003     1190    Perform:Com.Tent
  003     1239    Active:Perform
```

Here's the `dput`:

```
dat <- structure(list(user_id = c("001", "001", "001", "002", "002", 
  "002", "002", "002", "002", "002", "002", "002", "003", "003", 
  "003", "003"), log_id = c("1334", "1323", "1212", "1113", "1478", 
  "1134", "1256", "1590", "1345", "1478", "1134", "1256", "1590", 
  "1345", "1190", "1239"), categories = c("Perform:Sport_Well:Com.Tent", 
  "Com.Tent", "Active", NA, "Com.Tent:Active", "Sport_Well:Perform", 
  "Perform", "Perform", NA, "Com.Tent", "Sport_Well:Perform", "Perform", 
  "Perform", "Active:Perform", "Perform:Com.Tent", "Active:Perform")), 
  .Names = c("user_id", "log_id", "categories"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

The desired output is below:

```
user_id   category        NumActions
  001     Perform             1
  001     Sport_Well          1
  001     Com.Tent            2
  001     Active              1
  002     Com.Tent            2
  002     Active              1
  002     Perform             5
  002     Sport_Well          2
  003     Com.Tent            2
  003     Active              2
  003     Perform             4
```

I am trying to split categories, but cannot figure out how to count the log_ids with multiple categories.

```
df$cate = str_split(string = df$Ch_Category, pattern = ":")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following base R code gives same output but in different format:

```
> aa = aggregate(categories~user_id, data=dat, function(x) paste(x,collapse=':'))
> sapply(sapply(split(aa, aa$user_id), function(x) strsplit(x$categories, ':')  ), table )
$`001`

    Active   Com.Tent    Perform Sport_Well 
         1          2          1          1 

$`002`

    Active   Com.Tent    Perform Sport_Well 
         1          2          5          2 

$`003`

  Active Com.Tent  Perform 
       2        1        4
```

Comment: Thanks @mso, but I need to aggregate individual categories.

Answer (score 3):

**dplyr** Here is a dplyr solution:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
   group_by(user_id) %>% 
   do(strsplit(.$categories, ":") %>% 
        unlist %>% 
        table(dnn = "category") %>% 
        as.data.frame(responseName = "numActions", stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
```

which gives:

```
Source: local data frame [11 x 3]
Groups: user_id

   user_id categories numActions
1      001     Active          1
2      001   Com.Tent          2
3      001    Perform          1
4      001 Sport_Well          1
5      002     Active          1
6      002   Com.Tent          2
7      002    Perform          5
8      002 Sport_Well          2
9      003     Active          2
10     003   Com.Tent          1
11     003    Perform          4
```

Note that if you don't care about the heading names then we can omit `dnn=...` and `responseName=...` and if a warning which can be ignored is ok then we can omit `stringsAsFactors=...` so with those caveats it can be shortened to:

```
dat %>% 
   group_by(user_id) %>% 
   do(strsplit(.$categories, ":") %>% unlist %>% table %>% as.data.frame)
```

**data.table**  This can be done similarly in `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(dat)
DT[, as.data.frame(table(unlist(strsplit(categories, ":")), dnn = "categories"),
                 responseName = "numActions"), by = user_id]
```

and the shortened last statement with the caveat that the column names are not the same:

```
DT[, as.data.frame(table(unlist(strsplit(categories, ":")))), by = user_id]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. Since I am new to R, I don not understand "%>% ". I will appreciate if you can explain briefly how this code is working.

Comment: Read the magrittr package vignette.

Answer (score 2):

Split the strings in the column, add as rows to a temporary data frame and then do the counting. This example uses `dplyr` idioms, but I'm sure others will post base R solutions if you can't use `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

cats <- strsplit(dat$categories, ":")
tmp <- data.frame(user_id = rep(dat$user_id, sapply(cats, length)), categories = unlist(cats))
tmp %>% 
  group_by(user_id, categories) %>% 
  summarise(NumActions=n()) %>% 
  ungroup

##    user_id categories NumActions
## 1      001     Active          1
## 2      001   Com.Tent          2
## 3      001    Perform          1
## 4      001 Sport_Well          1
## 5      002     Active          1
## 6      002   Com.Tent          2
## 7      002    Perform          5
## 8      002 Sport_Well          2
## 9      002         NA          2
## 10     003     Active          2
## 11     003   Com.Tent          1
## 12     003    Perform          4
```

Answer (score 2):

I've been playing around with **tidyr** today, so here is a solution using that package.

First I `separate` the combined column into three.  I reshape the resulting dataset into a long format with `gather` (removing missing values).  Then I add up the numbers per group using **dplyr** `group_by` and `summarise`.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
```

Separate one column into three:

```
dat %>% 
    separate(categories, c("a", "b", "c"), sep = ":", extra = "merge")

   user_id log_id          a          b        c
1      001   1334    Perform Sport_Well Com.Tent
2      001   1323   Com.Tent       <NA>     <NA>
3      001   1212     Active       <NA>     <NA>
4      002   1113       <NA>       <NA>     <NA>
5      002   1478   Com.Tent     Active     <NA>
6      002   1134 Sport_Well    Perform     <NA>
7      002   1256    Perform       <NA>     <NA>
8      002   1590    Perform       <NA>     <NA>
9      002   1345       <NA>       <NA>     <NA>
10     002   1478   Com.Tent       <NA>     <NA>
11     002   1134 Sport_Well    Perform     <NA>
12     002   1256    Perform       <NA>     <NA>
13     003   1590    Perform       <NA>     <NA>
14     003   1345     Active    Perform     <NA>
15     003   1190    Perform   Com.Tent     <NA>
16     003   1239     Active    Perform     <NA>
```

Make into long format (one column for category):

```
dat %>% 
    separate(categories, c("a", "b", "c"), sep = ":", extra = "merge") %>%
    gather(variable, category, a:c, na.rm = TRUE)

   user_id log_id variable   category
1      001   1334        a    Perform
2      001   1323        a   Com.Tent
3      001   1212        a     Active
4      002   1478        a   Com.Tent
5      002   1134        a Sport_Well
6      002   1256        a    Perform
7      002   1590        a    Perform
...
```

And then group by `user_id` and `category` and count up number in each group.

```
dat %>% 
separate(categories, c("a", "b", "c"), sep = ":", extra = "merge") %>%
gather(variable, category, a:c, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
group_by(user_id, category) %>%
summarise(NumActions = n())

   user_id   category NumActions
1      001     Active          1
2      001   Com.Tent          2
3      001    Perform          1
4      001 Sport_Well          1
5      002     Active          1
6      002   Com.Tent          2
7      002    Perform          5
8      002 Sport_Well          2
9      003     Active          2
10     003   Com.Tent          1
11     003    Perform          4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [my `cSplit` function](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/11380733) along with `.N` from "data.table", like this:

```
cSplit(dat, "categories", ":", "long")[, list(NumActions = .N), 
                                       by = list(user_id, categories)]
#     user_id categories NumActions
#  1:     001    Perform          1
#  2:     001 Sport_Well          1
#  3:     001   Com.Tent          2
#  4:     001     Active          1
#  5:     002         NA          2
#  6:     002   Com.Tent          2
#  7:     002     Active          1
#  8:     002 Sport_Well          2
#  9:     002    Perform          5
# 10:     003    Perform          4
# 11:     003     Active          2
# 12:     003   Com.Tent          1
```

Note that this also counts `NA`, which you may or may not want. If you don't want it. A simple `na.omit` is all that would be required to remove those values. To remove the `NA` "categories", just add the following to the end of the above command:

```
[!is.na(categories)]
```